# Dynamic dropdown in laravel 5.3 with jquery not working correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am tryring to dynamically populate the constituencies in the constituency dropdown menu depending on the county selected in the first (counties) drop down. Only constituencies in the selected county should be listed in the constituencies dropdown otherwise the constituencies dropdown is empty.
I have the constituencies in the database with county_id as FK. 
What is actually happening when a county is selected, only the first four counties in the county dropdown menu will populate the constituencies. This other counties nothing happens when they are selected. Another daunting thing is that even those that populates the constituencies; the constituencies listed do not belong to the county selected.
I have checked and confirmed that constituencies table is correctly listed with its county_id. Am able to list each county with its constituencies using a query.
I have also checked that the county_id being send via ajax is the correct county_id for the selected county. When I access the url manually in the browser will return the correct list of constituencies for the county_id passed.

```
../constituency/4
```

This the result in json:

```
{"226":"Teso North","227":"Teso South","228":"Nambale","229":"Matayos","230":"Butula","231":"Funyula","232":"Budalangi"}
```

This my specific issues:

**1. What is causing some counties when selected to populate no results?**

**2. What is causing the populated results not to match the selected county yet when the url is accessed via the browser the results are correct. **

**My Form**

```
<!--County select menu-->
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'members.store', 
'method'=>'post', 'class' => 'form','files'=>true )) !!}
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('County') !!}
{!! Form::select('county_id',$counties,null, ['id'=>'county'],
array('require','class'=>'form-control',
    'placeholder'=>'Select County',
    'value'=>"{{ old('county_id') }}" ))!!}
</div>
<!--Constituencies drop down menu to populated with constituencies in the county selected-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Constituencies
        <select id="const" name="const" class="form-control input-sm" name="city_id">
            <option value=""></option>
       </select>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Save', 
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>

<!--Jquery include-->
 <script src="http://localhost/app/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<!--Jquery Code-->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
           $('select[name="county_id"]').on('change',
           function()
           {
            var county_id =$(this).val();
            if(county_id)
            {
            var url ='{!!route("consts")!!}'+county_id;

            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"json",

                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('select[name="const"]').empty();
                    $.each(data,
                        function(key,value)
                        {
                            $('select[name="const"]').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'<option>');
                        });
                }

            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('select[name="const"]').empty();
        }


           }) ;
        });

        </script>
```

**Laravel Route**

```
<!--   Laravel route-->

     Route::get('/constituency/{id}',['as'=>'consts','uses'=>'AjaxRequestsController@constituencies']);
```

**My controller Method**

```
<!--Controller Method in AjaxRequestsController-->
      public function constituencies($id)
    {
        $constituencies = Constituency::where('county_id',$id)->pluck('const_name','id');

        return $constituencies;

    }
```

**Model relationships**

```
//The Constituency model relationship
    public function county()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\County');
    }
    //The County model relationship

    public function constituency()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Constituency');
    }
```

The console returns no error.

what am I doing wrong. Kindly assist.

Comment: As a debugging technique: have you checked (in the network tab in Chrome Inspector) the right ajax call is made, and the right results are returned?

Comment: I am not well acquainted with debugging with network tab. I however what I noticed that all scripts has a status code of 200

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOQDrGrd9H8